# Defining VBA Static Variable Causes Compiler Error

Tags: vba, ms-word

According to Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2cty7t8(v=vs.100).aspx The following static variable declaration is correct.

```
Public Sub MyProc()
     static count as integer = 0
     count = count + 1 
End Sub
```

According to Word 2010 VBA, this is a compiler error. It wants:

```
Public Sub MyProc2()
     static count as integer
     count = count + 1 
End Sub
```

You have to assume that the static count is initialized to zero.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 4):

The link in your question refers to VB.NET, not VBA. VBA requires the syntax as in your second example.

The correct link is [Visual Basic for Applications Reference – Static Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266296(v=vs.60).aspx). There the syntax is described as follows:

> Static varname[([subscripts])] [As [New] type] [, varname[([subscripts])] [As [New] type]] . . .

As you can see there, VBA doesn't allow assigning a value in the same statement the static variable is declared.

Comment: FWIW, this isn't specific to `Static` - the only single line declaration\assignment VBA allows is `Dim foo As New SomeClass`.

Comment: `Static count As Integer: count = 1` ... declaration and assignment on single line :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you dee, Word VBA 2010 compiler likes this syntax. I prefer my static variables be defined instead of left to the whim of the compiler.

Static count As Integer: count = 1